# How to split large (vmdk) files on an ESXi 6.0 host?

Tags: ssh, backup, esxi

I've got a server running ESXi 6.0 in a data center and I need to do some backup of it. Currently it has three quite large disk images (1TB, 500GB, 500GB) and I need to download those. The only problem about it, is that my internet connection is only about 100 MBits and sometimes not that stable. Thus I'll need to interrupt that download some times. So the best would be splitting those monolithic disk images into parts (e.g. 20-100GB each), without affecting them, so that I can download them step by step.

The only problem with that idea is how to achieve that? How can I split them? While connecting to SSH I've noticed that there is no such thing as the `split` command I know from linux, and no `zip` and no `7z` which could be capable of splitting them.

One additional hint: I plan to rejoin them on a windows machine. There are quite easy solutions to rejoin simple split files like *hjsplit*.

Comment: I don't exactly know what utilities are available on ESXi but what about tar? That should be able to simply split as well. Providing a listing of the common binary directories might be helpful. With such a huge amount of data it might be worthwhile to just get into the data center with a spare disk/usb drive. Alternatively there should be protocols that allow you to resume. Check for rsync and sftp [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411225/how-to-resume-scp-with-partially-copied-files).

Comment: Neither `tar` nor `gzip` have any options for splitting. Any examples I could find, always involve `split`. But I'll give `rsync` a try.

Comment: I haven't tried to create archives of a particular size so far. You seem to be correct that it's not a native option in tar. At least not in the expected way. There is `--tape-length` and `--multi-volume` which should allow for it, even if it's a bit clunky. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size) has an example and also mentions that there might be reliability problem.

Comment: I've spent some hours now on trying rsync, but paused that for a moment as I've read about a lot of users having problems with it on ESXi. Maybe I even need to compile the latest version of it. Before spending that effort, i tried to investigate into your `--tape-length` hint. Well and here I've figured out, that the specific version of `tar` distributed with ESXi doesn't support that. At least not for my version. So it would have been a nice (but quite unhandy) idea, but this also doesn't work out for me.

Comment: I'm currently trying it by creating a local copy of the full VM image at the ESXi itself - so the users are not that long interrupted - and downloading that via SFTP with suspend/resume. Hopefully the file will be not corrupted afterwards. But `md5sum %FILE%` at ESXi and `certutil -hashfile %FILE% MD5` in windows should hopefully help to validate that. Never the less even creating the hash will take a lot of time. Anyway all of that is quite painful as it takes ages and I don't know whether it will finally work.

Comment: Finally that last described approach worked out for me. It took a long time, but it worked.